# Share this javascript blocked in private mode firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, ektron, sharethis

I was doing a test for some responsive coding on a website that uses Ektron, for all you Ektron wizards out there but the issue that I was noticing is in private mode. We use something called Share This which allows for instant social media sharing but then there are 2 icons one for facebook and one for twitter and those icons are hidden like the JS is being blocked because the CSS is still showing on the page for each of those classes.

Why would this be blocked in private mode in Firefox?

Unstripped version of the code:

```
  <div class="event_social">            
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="st_sharethis_custom" st_via="website" st_processed="yes">Share</a>
   <span class="st_facebook" st_via="website" st_processed="yes"><span style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; width: 16px;" class="stButton"><span class="chicklets facebook">&nbsp;</span></span></span>
    <span class="st_twitter" st_via="website" st_processed="yes"><span style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; width: 16px;" class="stButton"><span class="chicklets twitter">&nbsp;</span></span></span>
    <span class="st_email" st_processed="yes"><span style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; width: 16px;" class="stButton"><span class="chicklets email">&nbsp;</span></span></span>
    </div>
```

Stripped version of the code:

```
    <div class="event_social">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="st_sharethis_custom" st_via="website">Share</a>
        <span class="st_facebook" st_via="website"></span>
        <span class="st_twitter" st_via="website"></span>
        <span class="st_email"></span>         
     </div>
```

Anyone run into any issues like this before?

Comment: Do you have an Ad Blocker running in the private mode?

Comment: I don't see anything in the question specific to Ektron. Is the "unstripped" version prior to the execution of ShareThis JavaScript (view-source) or post (inspect element)?

Comment: I know its not specific to Ektron per se but the website runs on Ektron. No there is not any ad blocking bu the sharethis loads properly in Chrome Incognito mode. The unstripped version is when viewing using Dev Tools after page load.

Comment: Hmm if its not ad blocker do you see any JS errors in the console?

Comment: Oh in the console it does say it is blocked because of tracking protection. I am unfamiliar with that so I will need to research that. Thank you for assisting me with this @crazymatt

Comment: Awesome, glad you're getting it sorted out!

Comment: Privacy protection across domains, but Chrome doesn't do that if you go Incognito mode. Boo for Google! haha

Comment: hi even i am getting that same problem i am using stButtons.locateElements(); in my js code this stButtons is undefined is what the error i am getting only in firefox private browser can u help me in this if u get what the issue